# Pytest-drf unit tests and dict_items assert

Tags: pytest, assert

There is a code in a legacy project using pytest-drf and I'm new in Python and tests, I would like to know what an assert checking two dict_items is comparing, but could not find out neither other examples nor explanations about it.
Here's the code:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestPhones(Base)
    list_url = lambda_fixture(lambda: url_for('phones-list'))
    detail_url = lambda_fixture(
        lambda old_phone: url_for('phones-detail', old_phone.pk))

    class TestCreate(VerbTests.Create):
    data = phone_json
    def test_returned_json(self, data, json, model):
        expected = data.items()
        actual = json.items()
        assert expected <= actual
```

What is this assert code doing?

I couldn't understand why it's being used the lower symbol '<' for this assert, I see that it's comparing dict_items content in 'expected' and 'actual' received from the API in json format, but couldn't find what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

`assert <condition>` is used to check that an expected condition is fulfilled.
For more information on the testing and especially on assert, you can have a look on [Pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html)

While comparing the dictionaries, dict1<=dict2 returns True if dict1 is contained in dict2.

Here a code which show the different cases:

```py
my_dict = {"test1":"test_val1", "test2":"test_val2", "test3":"test_val3", "test4":"test_val4", "test5":"test_val5"}
for my_tuple in [
    (["test1", "test2"], ["test1", "test5"]),
    (["test1", "test2"], ["test1", "test2"]),
    (["test1", "test2"], ["test1"]),
    (["test1"], ["test1", "test5"]),
]:
    my_dict1 = {}
    my_dict2 = {}
    for key in my_tuple[0]:
        my_dict1[key] = my_dict[key]
    for key in my_tuple[1]:
        my_dict2[key] = my_dict[key]
    print(my_dict1.items() <= my_dict2.items(), "---", my_dict1, "<=", my_dict2)
```

The returned output

```
False --- {'test1': 'test_val1', 'test2': 'test_val2'} <= {'test1': 'test_val1', 'test5': 'test_val5'} # not contained
True --- {'test1': 'test_val1', 'test2': 'test_val2'} <= {'test1': 'test_val1', 'test2': 'test_val2'} # equal
False --- {'test1': 'test_val1', 'test2': 'test_val2'} <= {'test1': 'test_val1'} # not contained
True --- {'test1': 'test_val1'} <= {'test1': 'test_val1', 'test5': 'test_val5'} # contained
```

Comment: Thanks François, I edited the question to try to explain it better.
I have already used other assert checks using identical symbol '==', but in this comparison, why is it using lower symbol '<=' and how does it work for dict_items?